# console.log not fired when promise is executed

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

I have a js file in which i export a promise and i call it in another file.
I dnt understand why the console logs are not fired when i call the promise, 
maybe i dnt fully understand how promises work or maybe sth is wrong with the way i call the promise

pub.js

```
var config = require('../config');
var q = 'tasks';
var open = require('amqplib').connect('amqp://'+ config.rabbitmq.url);

module.exports =  open.then(function(conn) {
  return conn.createChannel();
}).then(function(ch) {
  return ch.assertQueue(q).then(function(ok) {
   console.log('inside publisher')
   const r = ch.sendToQueue(q, Buffer.from('something to do'));
   console.log('r',r)
     return r
  });
}).catch(console.warn);
```

index.js (where i call the promise)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var publisher = require('../connectors/pub');

var rabbitPromise = () => (
    new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        publisher
                .then(res=>{
                        console.log('-----------------------')
                        console.log('publishing now',res)
                        resolve(res)

                })
    })  

);
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', async(req, res, next) => {
    const result_pub = await rabbitPromise()  
    res.send('ok')
});
```

I expected to see the console.log('inside publisher') but i don't see it i only get console.log('-----------------------') and console.log('publishing now',res),

Comment: Notice that .then should be called on a Promise object. What is the role of publisher?

Comment: @jank the publisher publishes a msg to rabbitmq and returns true

Comment: Promises are not lazy, a chain will get executed immediately, so the "inside publisher" message will be logged as soon as the queue is asserted. Are you sure that the connection is actually made? It may take a while.

Answer (score 0):

the chaining in pub.js is not right. In order to call the promise, it would be something more like this :

```
module.exports =  open
   .then(function(conn) {
     return conn.createChannel();
   })
   .then(function(ch) {
     return ch.assertQueue(q);
   })
   .then(function(ok) {
      console.log('inside publisher')
      const r = ch.sendToQueue(q, Buffer.from('something to do'));
      console.log('r',r)
      return r
   })
   .catch(console.warn);
```

Comment: sth is wrong with with this code : 'ch' is not defined in  const r = ch.sendToQueue(q, Buffer.from('something to do'));

Comment: indeed, you first implementation is good, i suspect assertQueue(q) error not catched, maybe you can try `ch.assertQueue(q).then(...).catch(r=> throw new Error(r))` in your code and see if you have a console warning ?